# Wiki for spreadsheets / tabular data

Tags: wiki, spreadsheet

[Wikipedia has tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_electoral_systems#Compliance_of_selected_single-winner_methods), but

- they're always part of an article, not standalone
- editing with VisualEditor is clunky
- editing with wikicode is a nightmare
- sometimes they can be sorted, but that's about all you can do as far as viewing

GitHub [will display CSV files as tables](https://gist.github.com/endolith/c4b8e1e3c630a260424123b4e9d964c4), but

- editing plain text CSV is not fun
- no sorting or formatting or anything, just a table that you can scroll
- collaborating requires learning git, commiting to repos, etc.

Plot.ly has [tables that can be published](https://plot.ly/~endolith/54.embed)

- but I think they can only be forked, not collaboratively edited

Is there anything that's easier to edit, collaboratively edited like a wiki, and allows viewers to rearrange or filter large tables to dig out the information they want?  Both links above are examples of the type of data I'm thinking of, like tables of properties of many things in the same category, product feature comparisons, etc.

Comment: https://app.retable.io/ "Try The Awesome Collaborative Online Spreadsheet Tool With No Login"

Answer (score 1):

I just realized Google Sheets can do this, if you set it to public and give editing access to "Anyone":

> [image]

I was able to edit it without being logged in, and it's credited to "Anonymous".

Not quite like a wiki, but definitely a publicly-editable spreadsheet with revision history, so probably the closest I will get.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that Mediawiki actually supports tabular data: [Help:Tabular Data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tabular_Data)  Though it's actually in a JSON format and there's no nice editor, so this is not a good solution (yet).  It's more for re-using the data on other pages, but:

> Eventually, we hope there will be a spreadsheet-like editor to simplify data editing.

Example: [Data:Ncei.noaa.gov/weather/New York City.tab](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data:Ncei.noaa.gov/weather/New_York_City.tab)